# How to get tile for click event in leaflet marker cluster?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

Here is my code.

```
function onMapClick(e) {
    e.originalEvent.defaultPrevented = true;
    var orig = e.originalEvent;
    console.log(orig.target);
}
map.on('click', onMapClick);
```

console.log will show the **tile** i.e

```
<img class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" ... />
```

But i could not able to find the **tile** when I use leaflet marker cluster.
  How to get the **tile** in leaflet marker cluster with map click event?

Answer (score 2):

Best way to get tile is to calculate it from coordinates. There are many calculating implementations on [OpenStreetMap wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames).

Here you have [working example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4zcys/). Just use it in `map.on` event method:

```
map.on('click', function(e) {
 console.log(getTileURL(e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng, map.getZoom()));
});
```