# Substitute bitwise operation in ESLint

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, eslint

I'm trying to apply this code: [How to get X Y Z coordinates of tile by click on Leaflet map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513646/how-to-get-x-y-z-coordinates-of-tile-by-click-on-leaflet-map) - which contains bitwise operator "<<". In the environment that I'm running it on (NodeJS, ExpressJS, AngularJS), codes are checked by ESLint upon compiling it but I need the solution given on the link. I get this error on compilation .

> Unexpected use of '<<'  no-bitwise

According to this link: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-bitwise - ESLint disallows bitwise operators. Is there any way to bypass this rule or if not, provide an alternate calculation  that produces similar results to bitwise operation '<<'?

I hope my question is clear, thanks.

Comment: Each bit you shift left is the same as multiplying with its self. Power of two. So `2<<3` is the same as `Math.pow(2,3)`. Will work for all numbers except 1, you will have to treat that as a special case. `c = a << b` can be done `c = a===1?Math.pow(2,b-1):Math.pow(a,b);`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to add the comment `//eslint-disable-line no-bitwise` on the line you'd like for es-lint to ignore

e.g.

```
var x = 5 << 5; //eslint-disable-line no-bitwise
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm.

Comment: @YuriZarubin is there any other alternative to do the same thing without adding `//eslint-disable-line no-bitwise` in the source code. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

For power of two you can use `Math.pow`

```
const scale = Math.pow( 2, zoom );
```